# How do I find the basis of this column space?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I have reduced it to echleon form: [image]

However, my answer was the third and fourth column, but that is apparently wrong...

Comment: No, the basis is given by the columns with pivots - so the first and second column. And it must be the first/second columns of the original matrix, not the echelon form.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reduce the matrix to the echelon form, and take note of the columns that have a pivot entry. Return to the original matrix and take the corresponding columns to be the basis for the column space. So for this matrix, it would reduce in such a manner that the first two columns have leading entries, so the basis for ColA would be {(-4,-3,-2),(-2,-1,-2)} and has a dimension of two.

Comment: I would rather say *a* basis, not *the* basis.

Comment: Yes your right, my mistake! This would just be an example of a possible basis